# Celery starts task that is commented out

Tags: celery, django-celery

In my tasks.py file, I'm attempting to import some python scripts from a folder. For unknown reasons, when I attempt to run:

```
celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

It's going to automatically run one of the scripts I've imported: btcbidask.bitfinex(), without me even calling it.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
#External imports
import sys
sys.path.append('/daemons/')

from celery import shared_task, Celery

#Own imports
from daemons.btcbidask import bitfinex
#from daemons.btctrades import bitfinex

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0')

# @shared_task
# def btcbidask():
#   btcbidask.bitfinex()

# @shared_task
# def btctrades():
#   btctrades.bitfinex()
```

And even though all of my shared tasks are commented out, it's still going to run the "bitfinex" function on its own. I am very puzzled.